# General question about RPCs

Tags: rpc

Can I generate account through curl jsonrpc?? I couldn't find in official developer docs.

How can I list up account lists through curl jsonrpc?

How can I search transaction detail information based on tx hash through curl jsonrpc?
also I couldn't find the way on official developer docs.
For search the transaction details based on tx hash, should I settled up conseil on local enviroment?

I have knew that I am able to propagation tx based on curl jsonrpc POST ..//helpers/forge/operations .
But I don't know how to sign operation through curl jsonrpc request?

https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html is so strange. especially protocol alpha section.
some rpcs works others not.
is there new rpc docs about for it?

Answer (score 2):

> Can I generate account through curl jsonrpc?? I couldn't find in official developer docs.

There are two kinds of accounts: implicit accounts and smart contracts.

To generate an implicit account, you don't need to talk to a node, you just need to generate a pair of cryptographic keys using one of the supported encryption schemes; the address of the implicit account is essentially the hash of its public key.

Generating a smart contract however is called an origination and the RPC for it the same as for the other operations: https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-forge-operations; you are advised to simulate it using https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-preapply-operations before.

> How can I list up account lists through curl jsonrpc?

I think you are looking for 
https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#get-block-id-context-contracts

> How can I search transaction detail information based on tx hash through curl jsonrpc?

I am not sure but I would try https://tezos.gitlab.io/api/rpc.html#post-block-id-helpers-parse-operations.

> But I don't know how to sign operation through curl jsonrpc request?

You don't want the node to sign on your behalf as this would mean that it knows your private key.

> some rpcs works others not. is there new rpc docs about for it?

More or less. The RPC doc is generated from the shell and the protocol code. The protocol has just been automatically upgraded a few hours ago through the on-chain governance procedure. The Alpha protocol in the source tree will be updated soon to match the code that now runs on mainnet.

However this update has very small impact on RPCs so I am not sure this will fix the problem you have. Can you please list the broken RPCs?